# Find unanswered emails using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to find all unanswered emails in a folder with Microsoft Graph.
The closest thing I could find is the [PidTagLastVerbExecuted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtaglastverbexecuted-canonical-property) attribute, which gives me the last executed verb, e.g.:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=parentFolderId eq '<my_folder_id>'&$select=subject,parentFolderId&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'Integer 0x1081')
```

However, if an email was first replied to and then forwarded, the LastVerbExecuted is "forwarded", not "answered".
So how can I find out with certainty if an email in the inbox has been answered?
In IMAP there is the "ANSWERED" Flag, but I cannot find anything like that in Graph.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent IMAP property is pidtagmessagestatus https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagmessagestatus-canonical-property eg to find answered emails (replied or forwarded)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep:ep/id eq 'Integer 0x0E17' and cast(ep/value, Edm.Int32) eq 512)
```

or unanswered would be

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep:ep/id eq 'Integer 0x0E17' and cast(ep/value, Edm.Int32) ne 512)
```

The one thing to be careful of is that its a bitwise value and the Graph doesn't allow you to filter on bitwise values (EWS does have a bitwise search filters). So there could be edge cases where something else may use that property that would break the graph filter so I would suggest you put a client side filter to also check the bitwise value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I do not quite understand the part about breaking the filter. How would something else use the property? Is it not defined for one thing only? 
And what do you mean by putting a client side filter? Isn't that what I'm doing with your example code?

Comment: What's worse, it does not seem to work for me... 
I tried:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=parentFolderId eq '<my_folder_id>' and singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep:ep/id eq 'Integer 0x0E17' and cast(ep/value, Edm.Int32) eq 512)&$select=subject`
It gives me all emails in the folder for `ne 512` and none with `eq 512`, even though there are several emails in the folder which have been either replied to or forwarded or both (or neither).

Comment: . How would something else use the property? Its a bitwise value so one flag MSGSTATUS_ANSWERED is 0x00000200 but MSGSTATUS_TAGGED is 0x00000002 so if both flags where set the value would be 0x00000202 hence you integer filter would fail. I would suggest looking at the items with a Mapi editor it maybe an IMAP or POP client is using the flag so try it on a clean mailbox with no other clients are accessing

Comment: Thank you for clarifying about the bitwise nature of the property, I understand that now. 
I cannot test it though, since my example is not working properly (see other comment). Do you have tips for that? Am I using it wrong?

Comment: why filter on parentFolderId that not a good idea just use the parentFolderId in https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/parentFolderId/messages you'll get much better performance.  If you just ask for the value of that property what do you see? are they all 0?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That's a better way to get the folder.
Yes, they are all 0 when I do: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/<my_folder_id>/messages?$select=subject&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'Integer 0x0E17')`